# Grouping java classes in packages convention in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, coding-style

Currently I have Android Studio project with 13 classes in main application package. I decided that it's time to group classes in separate folders (java packages?) like Activities, Fragments, Models, Utils, etc. How to do it correctly following some kind of convention (if there is any) especially for Android Studio project?

What I should select here when I want to create new folder for class group? "Package"? How to name it (following convention) after creation?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if there are some "official" convention.

My current package structure I use:
"root" (which is often equals to appId) package for single application class.
If app consists from one activity, one services, then they can be put here as well.

Then, "root".*`component_name`* package if you app consist of a lot of separated heavy components (usually it doesn't) which hold own activities, models and etc.

"root" package or each component's package contains:

- `activity` for activities and fragments
- `app`. Also, sometimes, I create `app` package which can contain base classes for activities, fragments, services and other android app components.
- `view` for views and adapters
- `model` contains business logic. Contains interfaces, entities, DTOs.
- `model.impl`: from time to time, I use it. It contains model implementation(s)(package visibility)
- `helper` or `util`.

  - `helper` contains domain specific things. As side note: usually I try to avoid using them by encapsulating of helper logic right into domain data type.
  - Package `util` usually goes to "root" package.
    `app`.

Last time I started to use `async` or `model.async` packages for classes which describe asynchronous computation, background jobs etc.

---

I'm not always happy with such structure. So,
I look to how classes are grouped inside android api.
Also I like to discover structure of my favorite libraries and frameworks.

---

**Example:**

`org.android.exampleapp.app`

```
          BaseActivity.class   // provide access to MyService
          BaseFragment.class
```

`org.android.exampleapp.activity`

```
          LaunherActivity.class  // extend BaseActivity and BaseFragment
          MainActivity.class
          MyDetailsFragment.class
          MyListFragment.class
```

`org.android.exampleapp.model`

```
          SuperItem.class
          MyService.class
```

`org.android.exampleapp.model.impl`

```
          MyServiceOfflineImpl.class
          MyServiceOnlineImpl.class
```

`org.android.exampleapp.async`

```
          GetSuperItemsTask.class
```